# Data Views Data Extension Copy

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

Is there a way to replicate the system data views as standard data extensions?  I'd rather not build each one of these.  Use case is that I need to keep this data longer than the 6 months data retention policy.

I'm thinking there might be some SSJS that I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say: You have to build every one of these by hand.

Create all the DataExtensions as shown in documentation and built them. Its only a few (shouldnt take more than 2 hours).

After that just do an SQL Add and Update from each _DataView. Then you can set the retention policy from your created dataextension as you wish.